# kendojs mobile - how do i bind to a data-title?

Tags: data-binding, kendo-mobile

I have a drawer-layout

I would like to bind to the data-title attribute but I can not figure out how to do this.

My DataSource looks like this:

```
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
var dataOrg = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://webapi.dynacalbeta.com/api/org?DynaCalPath=" + urlParams['Org'],
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            data: {}
        }
    },
    error: function (e, a, b) {
        console.log("Error:" & e & a & b);
    },
    success: function (obj, txt, xhr) {
        console.log("Success:" & txt);
    }
});
```

I want the data-title to be filled with {data.Name}
Thanks for any help.
Shawn

Comment: Hi,
  You can't directly set data-title value using VM. You need to do some workaround in data-init/data-show method.
Post your sample code here, so that we can help you

Comment: What do mean {data.Name}.? Where is it resides..?